# Управление прибором с компьютера через COM порт на Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, com-порт, rs232

Добрый день,

Мне нужно реализовать программу управления прибором E7-25. Подключается этот прибор к компьютеру через usb кабель, и при подключении создается виртуальный com-порт. Подключиться к этому порту у меня получается, передачу данных и прием данных проверял при помощи Virtual Serial Port Driver, и данные отправляются и передаются, но при отправке данных на прибор в виде:
char data[] = "(0xAA, 14)";
прибор не отвечает вообще ничего.

Вот код моей программы

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

HANDLE hSerial;

void ReadCOM()
{
      DWORD iSize;
      char sReceivedChar[20];
      while (true)
      {
            ReadFile(hSerial, &sReceivedChar, 20, &iSize, 0);
            if (iSize > 0)
                cout << sReceivedChar;
      }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LPCTSTR sPortName = L"COM4";  

    hSerial = ::CreateFile(sPortName,GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
    if(hSerial==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if(GetLastError()==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            cout << "serial port does not exist.\n";
        }
        cout << "some other error occurred.\n";
    }


    DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength=sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    if (!GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
    {
        cout << "getting state error\n";
    }
    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_9600;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize=8;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity=NOPARITY;
    if(!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
    {
        cout << "error setting serial port state\n";
    }
    char data[] = "(0xAA, 64)";
    DWORD dwSize = sizeof(data);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten;
    LPOVERLAPPED ov;

    BOOL iRet = WriteFile (hSerial,data,dwSize,&dwBytesWritten ,NULL);

    cout << dwSize << " Bytes in string. " << dwBytesWritten << " Bytes sended. " << endl;

    while(1)
    {
        ReadCOM();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

В документации к прибору написано, что команды ему нужно посылать в следующем формате
Формат обмена:

```
ПК — E7-25: 0xAA, №команды, [параметры].
Е7-25 — ПК: 0xAA, №команды, [параметры].
```

То есть вот что должна возвращать та команда, которую я по умолчанию отправляю

```
    64 – Получить имя прибора
    ПК — (0xAA, 64); E7-25 — (0xAA, 64, “Е725”)
```

Поэтому  у меня есть вопросы. 
Правильно ли я отправляю данные в порт? И правильно ли я их принимаю из порта?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Первое и самое главное: настройки порта. Второе и очевидное: char data[] = "(0xAA, 64)"; - фигня. Прибор наверняка не ждет скобочек и прочего, а ждет два байта 0xAA и 0x40

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, то есть отсутствие ошибки при открытии порта не говорит о том, что настройки порта на компьютере и на приборе совпадают?

Comment: Конечно не говорит, у COM-порта нет таких функций

Answer (score 1):

Протокол связи с прибором у Вас - очевидно бинарный, Вы сами его привели. Затем Вы зачем-то посчитали двоичные данные - строкой, а потом добавили по бокам ещё два байта скобок плюс нулевой байт на конце:

```
char data[] = "(0xAA, 64)"; // эквивалентно: char data[11] = {'(', '0', 'x', 'A', 'A', ',', ' ', '6', '4', ')', 0x00}
```

Зачем это было сделано? Возможно, стоит подучить синтаксис.
Нужно сформировать массив этих двух байтов, чтобы не было ничего лишнего

```
char data[2] = {0xAA, 64};
DWORD dwSize = 2;
// ...
```

После чего просто отправить эти два байта в устройство.

Comment: Развернул ответ.

Comment: @bobrof, сделал как вы советуете, потом попробовал поменять char на byte, данные в порт ушли, а ответа нет, можете что-нибудь сказать по поводу функции чтения данных с порта?

Comment: @Sergey, при чтении данных из порта тоже есть проблемы. Вы запрашиваете за раз по 20 байт в бесконечном цикле (который обёрнут в ещё один бесконечный цикл в основной функции).

Comment: @Sergey ...проблема здесь в том, что в вашем случае каждое такое чтение данных выходит из ReadFile только по тайм-ауту (или не выходит никогда, если тайм-аут не задан). 
То есть, если тайм-аут задан, скажем, 10 минут, то ответ от прибора Вы получите только через 10 минут. Или вообще не получите никогда (что зачастую и происходит при значениях по умолчанию).

В общем, Вам необходимо для начала установить разумное значение тайм-аута для чтения данных (да и на на запись тоже неплохо было бы). И читать по одному байту, а не по 20.

Comment: @Sergey Кроме того, функция вывода на экран у вас не слишком информативная. Вместо вывода самого байта на экран (char b; cout << b), для бинарных протоколов лучше выводить шестнадцатеричное **значение** этого байта: char b; std::cout << " 0x" << std::noshowbase << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int) b;